# Not able to download/open files with direct link in IIS7

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have some files that available for users to view or download, those files are listed with direct link (http://web_site.com/files/document.doc). Currently the issue that I'm facing is, every time I click on the link, it will prompt me for login. When I clicked on another link, it will ask me to login again.
I had granted the folder with IIS_IUSRS (Modify, Read & execute, List folder contents, Read and Write access). Please let me know if I miss out any access.

Comment: What kind of login? Check web.config for authentication settings

Comment: hi @Raptor. It's a window that look exactly like this, http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/mof/errors/win7a.png.